# Compute: $|z + 2| = |z − 3i|$

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Find all complex numbers that solve this equation:  $|z + 2| = |z − 3i|$

How would I go on about solving this one? 4 times? Like this?

$I. z+2=z-3i$

$II. z+2 = -(z-3i)$

$III. -(z+2) = z-3i$

$IV. -(z+2) = -(z-3i)$

Comment: $|x|=|y| \iff x=\pm x$ holds only for real numbers, because $|t|=1$ iff $t=\pm1$. In the complex numbers, the solution of $|z|=1$ are the whole unit circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have: $\left|\dfrac{z+2}{z-3i}\right| = 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{z+2}{z-3i} = e^{j\theta}$. You can take it from here.

Comment: @OC-Sasoo, nice. didn't think of that.

Comment: I'm a newbie.. What exactly is $e^{j0}$ and how do I take it from there?

Comment: @NejcPisk,  $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ is called the Euler's formula, a very useful one for all kinds of things.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this is by thinking of it geometrically.  The equation
$$|z + 2| = |z − 3i|$$
says that the distance of $z$ from $-2$ is equal to the distance of $z$ from $3i$.  This is true if and only if $z$ lies on the line which is the perpendicular bisector of the interval joining $-2$ and $3i$.  This line passes through the point $(-1,\frac32)$ and has gradient $-\frac23$, so its equation is
$$y-\frac32=-\frac23(x+1)\ .$$

Answer (score 4):

if you interpret $|z-a|$ as the distance between the points $z$ and $a$ in the complex plane, the equality you have can be interpreted as finding all points $z$ that are equal from points $-2$ and $3i.$

the points is the perpendicular bisector of the points $-2$ and $3i$. this is given by the parametric equation 
$z = -1 + 1.5i + t(3-2i)$ where $t$ is any real number.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest writing $z$ as $a + bi$, so you have

$$|a + bi + 2| = |a + bi - 3i|$$
$$\sqrt{(a+2)^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + (b - 3)^2}$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+4a + 4 + b^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 6b + 9}$$

Since both radicands are necessarily positive, we can write:

$$a^2+4a + 4 + b^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 6b + 9$$
$$4a - 5 + 6b = 0$$

So it's all complex numbers along a straight line:

$$b = -\frac 23 a + \frac 56$$
$$z = a + \left( -\frac 23 a + \frac 56\right)i$$

Comment: You made a mistake when you transformed $(a+2)^2$ into $a^2+2a+4$, when it should've been: $a^2+4a+4$.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows

$$|z + 2| = |z − 3i|\iff |z + 2|^2 = |z − 3i|^2 \iff (z+2)(\overline{z+2})=(z-3i)(\overline{z-3i})\\ \iff (z+2)(\overline{z}+2)=(z-3i)(\overline{z}+3i) \iff z\overline{z}+2z+2\overline{z}=z\overline{z}+3iz-3i\overline{z}+9 \\ \iff (2-3i)z+(2+3i)\overline{z}=5. $$

Writing $z=x+iy$ it is

$$(2-3i)(x+iy)+(2+3i)(x-iy)=5 \iff 4x+6y=5. $$

Thus the solution is the set $\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}:4x+6y=5\},$ that is a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use $z=a+bi$, where 
$$|z|=\sqrt{(a+bi)\overline{(a+bi)}} =\sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
So your equation is

$$ (a-2)^2+b^2=a^2+(b-3)^2\implies -4a+4 =  -6b+9\implies b=(4a-5)/6 $$

So we have for all $a\in\mathbb R$, 
$$ z= a+\frac{4a-5}{6}i$$

Comment: $a + 2$, not $a - 2$

Comment: The result should've been $z = a + \frac{-4a+5}{6}i$